# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\include\result.php on li

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
<?php
    class Result{

        protected $db_table        =  "result";
        protected $db_table_fields =  array();

        public $english;
        public $urdu;
        public $math;
        public $physics;
        public $chemistry;
        public $biology;

        public $english_grade;
        public $urdu_grade;
        public $math_grade;
        public $physics_grade;
        public $chemistry_grade;
        public $biology_grade;

        public function grading(){

            if($this->english >= 90 && $this->english <= 100)
                $this->english_grade = "A";
            else if($this->english >= 80 && $this->english < 90)
                $this->english_grade = "B";
            else if($this->english >= 70 && $this->english < 80)
                $this->english_grade = "C";
            else if($this->english >= 50 && $this->english < 70)
                $his->english_grade  = "D";
            else ($this->english >= 0 && $this->english <  50)
                $this->english_grade = "Fail";

        }

    }//class ends here
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else ($this->english >= 0 && $this->english <  50)
     $this->english_grade = "Fail";
```

Else doesn't expect a condition which is why `$this` is unexpected.

```
$his->english_grade  = "D";
```

This also looks like another error that will affect functionality.